# Gradient Background for JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, gradient, jtoolbar

I Want to set gradient background color for JToolBar in Java.
Am able to set this gradient effect for JPanel.

Thanks,
Sathish

Comment: You should also **ask a question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other Swing component, you must override its `paintComponent(...)` method. For instance,

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // Create the 2D copy
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    // Apply vertical gradient
    g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.WHITE, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLUE));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    // Dipose of copy
    g2.dispose();
}
```

If you want this gradient to show through the components on the `JToolBar`, you must invoke `setOpaque(false)` on each of those components.

Comment: @Sathish, no problem! I'm just confused by the fact that you said you were able to do this for `JPanel`, but unable to do it for `JToolBar`...:)